# Python Numpy - What is numpy.numarray?

Tags: python, string, numpy

When experimenting with Numpy, I found:

```
In [1]: numpy.numarray
Out[1]: 'removed'

In [2]: type(numpy.numarray)
Out[2]: str
```

What is `numpy.numarray`? What is it's purpose in Numpy? Why does it only say `'removed'`?

Comment: Do you know what it did before it was removed? What purpose did it serve? I'm just curious to find out.

Comment: just check for what you need on github https://github.com/numpy/numpy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`numarray`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/NumArray) was a predecessor of `numpy`. A long time ago, there were several packages (`numarray`, `numeric`), which had lots of overlap, and eventually were superceded by `numpy`.

(Wikipedia has a [whole section on `numpy` history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NumPy#History), if you're into this sort of stuff.)

`numarray` was [removed in 1.9](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.numarray.html). It has probably been replaced by this string, so that attempts to reference it would lead to something legible. In any case, there is nothing useful in this anymore.